# Esper Aggregation Results

Tags: sql, sum, aggregation, complex-event-processing, esper

Let's assume that I have an event. The event has 5 columns. A type column, a name column,a calling number,a detection timestamp column and a charge column. Esper produces the following 9 tuples:

```
[Event, CallPOPDWH, 385984MBSNE, time_1, 10]  
[Event, CallPOPDWH, 385984MBSNE, time_2, 30]
[Event, CallPOPDWH, 3859157UQHNI,time_3, 40]
[Event, CallPOPDWH, 3859157UQHNI,time_4, 40]
[Event, CallPOPDWH, 385984MBSNE, time_5, 40]
[Event, CallPOPDWH, 3859157UQHNI,time_6, 45]
[Event, CallPOPDWH, 385984MBSNE, time_7, 30]
[Event, CallPOPDWH, 385984MBSNE, time_8, 90]
[Event, CallPOPDWH, 385984MBSNE, time_9, 70]
```

I want to write a query which will return as results,for each calling number,all the detection timestamps,as long as the sum of the charge is greater than 100.As long as it finds for example tuples for the calling numbers:

```
385984MBSNE,3859157UQHNI with sum(charge)>100
```

it shall return:

```
[385984MBSNE,[time_1, time_2, time_5,time_7],120]
[3859157UQHNI,[time_3, time_4, time_6],125]
[385984MBSNE,[time_8, time_9],160]
```

The important thing is that the window which stores the timestamps for each calling number,closes when the sum of the charge is greater that 100.Then it shall open again until it finds tuples which will match the sum>100 condition.I have tried something like:

```
select calling_number,
       window(timestamp).distinctOf(),
       sum(charge)
from Event.std:groupwin(calling_number).win:expr_batch(sum(total_call_charge_amount) > 100)
group by calling_number
```

or

```
select calling_number,
       window(timestamp).distinctOf(),
       sum(charge)
from Event.std:groupwin(calling_number).win:time(120 second))
group by calling_number
having sum(e.total_call_charge_amount) > 100
```

Neither of the them seems to work properly.I observed that the timestamps window doesnt delete the previous timestamps.Any help would be greatly aprreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
select calling_number,
       window(timestamp).distinctOf(),
       sum(charge)
from Event.win:time(120 second))
group by calling_number
having sum(total_call_charge_amount) > 100
```

The group-by clause wasn't right. Otherwise what you had was pretty close.

Windows don't close. I think what you are trying to say is either that you only want to output the first row (use output first) every 120 secondes or that you want to throw away all accumulated data for a calling number and start over (see contexts or named windows for that) or something else?

For starting over from zero after output occurs for a given calling_number, this is one solution that uses a named window.

```
create window EventWindow#time(120) as Event;

insert into EventWindow select * from Event;

insert into ThresholdDetected select calling_number,  window(timestamp).distinctOf(), sum(charge)
from EventWindow
group by calling_number
having sum(total_call_charge_amount) > 100;

on ThresholdDetected as td delete from EventWindow as ew where ew.calling_number = td.calling_number;
```

Comment: You are totally right.I wrote it by mistake and i corrected it.What i want is that if esper finds some tuples for each calling_number whose sum for the total_call_charge_amount is greater than 100,then it should output the timestamps of these tupples.Then it should continue the same process for the same calling_number if it keeps receiving such tuples and as long as  the sum condition is served.Meanwhile,it should forget the previous timestamps for that calling if it has output it.You re right that i should see the context chapter in esper's manual however some help would be nice.

Comment: Together with forgetting the timestamps, does the sum change? So when there is output for "385984MBSNE" does the sum go to zero or does the sum stay at 120 or does the sum go to 30 which is the last arriving event's value?

Comment: According to my example for 385984MBSNE: 10+30+40+30=110.Now sum>100 so we get the output with the 4 timestamps.Then sum becomes zero.After one event: sum=90.Then the mext event comes so : 90+70=160 so sum>100 and we get output again with the 2 timestamps.The same procedure continues as long as more tuples for 385984MBSNE come.

Comment: The only problem i am dealing with is the fact that esper doesnt delete the previous results for a specific calling_number once sum is greater than 100.In my example,its outputs:   
           [385984MBSNE,[time_1, time_2, time_5,time_7],120]
           [385984MBSNE,[time_1, time_2, time_5,time_7,time_8, time_9],280]
Instead of what i wanted as mentioned above.

Comment: Ok if I understand correctly you want to start over at sum zero with no records. A named window may be the simplest. I'll update the answer.

Comment: You re approach is good.However,your query deletes all the data about the specific calling_number.What i want is that once we get the first output for a calling number then the window(timestamp) is cleared and sum equal to zero.That way,we get more tuples for the same calling number the query will be executed again.In your query,if we cant get more tuples for the same calling number as we delete them.I want to delete only the data that have been processed.

Comment: That is what is does.

Comment: It can process more tuples for the same calling number after deleting the processed ones.

Comment: Unfortunately it can't.I tried it and it produces only one tuple for that calling_number.After that it deletes the rest fromEventWindow for that calling_ number.

Comment: For example if it has 9 tuples for calling_number_1.When processing 3 tuples it finds that sum>100,so i outputs the 3 timestamps.Then it will delete everything with calling_number_1 so it will loose the rest 6 tuples.It wont calculate anything for it.

Comment: After the first 3 tuples there is one output row. Then it deletes the 3 tuples since the remaining 6 tuples have not been sent yet (Esper is stream processor, output occurs after 3 tuples and more output after more tuples are being sent in). Test online at http://esper-epl-tryout.appspot.com